# How to load balance jobs using spring batch when different nodes has different times?

Tags: quartz-scheduler, spring-batch

We have so many batch jobs to handle.
Now problem is we have 7 different nodes which has same application deployed(We use JBoss AS 7.1.1. as a application server) and We use Spring batch using quartz scheduler to schedule jobs.And it works just fine.
But 1 of our nodes is diff time then others (e.g. Suppose we have 3 nodes A,B,C so when there's a 12:00:00 in C there's a 11:58:00 in A and B) and all these nodes are been maintained by client.
So when any trigger fires(we use cron trigger) job run on single node only.
Now specific time(take 12:00) we need to fire more than one job, then all of them runs on a single node as all of them were timed out earlier the other nodes(As 12:00 o'clock happened in C before A and B).
I was wondering do we have any such mechanism where we take reference of any centralized time to time out all batch processes(like do not time out batch process when there's 12 O'clock on C but run batch job when there's a 12 O'clock in DB)..?
Thanks in advance :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Batch provides facilities to launch jobs via messages in the spring-batch-integration module.  I'd recommend managing the scheduling from a central point and having it send messages to the servers to be picked up based on the server's availability to run the job.  This would also address the issue of time synchronization as the scheduling piece would be handled in a central point.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your client to synchronize servers using [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol). All of your servers should have same time PERIOD. You will have bunch of other problems if you allow your servers stay out of synch with each other.

Comment: We already suggested it sir but seems they are not ready for it !!